# C# created bitmap does not get displayed in Internet Explorer 8 (Firefox works fine)

Tags: bitmapimage

I have problems to display a bitmap which I create in my C# Application. I create following bitmap:

```
int w = 150; 
int h = w/3; 
Bitmap aBMP = new Bitmap(w, h); 
using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(aBMP)) 
{ ...G.FillRectangle(...) } //here I am painting an image
```

later in the application I am saving the image as following:

```
aBMP.Save(anIMGfilename);
```

By a right click on the resulting image properties I dont receive the sercurity tab which I get with any other Bitmap image. Have you ever seen this behavior?

Comment: Can you post a URL where we can visit the problem? Does the HTML and CSS work with IE 8 when you use it directly in an HTML document so that we can be sure the problem is related to XSLT creating the HTML? It would help if you post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. So please show us a minimal but complete XML input document and XSLT stylesheet allowing us to reproduce the problem with the image not being rendered in IE 8.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I needed to change content of the initial question because the root cause is another. Do you have any new idea for this "adjusted" question?

Comment: No, I probably read the original question because it was tagged as XSLT, the current question seems to be completely unrelated and is rather vague (in which application exactly do you right-click to see a security tab?)

Comment: If you click on any image in the file explorer with right mouse button, a context menu pops up and you can select the properties. If I do that for example with a photo which has a bitmap format, I get this security tab, but if I click on the bitmap which I draw by myself like in the code above, it is not there. I dont know whether this a hint why the IE8 cannot display it, it was just an the only difference I could find out between the two images.

Answer (score 0):

When you use position absolute you must not use float,and u must set left and top and its parent has a position relative

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
#frame{
  position:relative;
}
#image {    
position: absolute;     
text-align: right;  
height: 70px;   
width: 400px;  
left:0;
top:10px;   
}
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I adjusted the code but nothing changes. The picture is still shown as an empty frame with the red cross in the internet explorer. Even by right click on the context menu to display the image nothing happens.

Comment: This also didnt help to solve the issue. Please see my updated question. I am still desperate to solve that and so hope you have an idea.